# How to use trig on screen coordinates to calculate angle between points

Tags: math, go, trigonometry

I am working on a game. This game is top down, real-time, and must feature pathing. My game must calculate the angle between a player's current position and the one they click to walk to.
Problem is, I am using screen coordinates, as in "x increases to the right, y increases to the bottom"

Here's where I'm at with some code

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math"
)

func main() {
  position1 := &Position{550, 200}
  position2 := &Position{700, 500}
  vector1 := CreatePathVector(position1, position2, 50)

  fmt.Printf("position1: %v\nposition2: %v\n", position1, position2)

  position := position1
  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    position = position.Add(vector1)
    fmt.Printf("next position: %v\n", position)
  }

  position3 := &Position{400, 500}
  position4 := &Position{700, 400}
  vector2 := CreatePathVector(position3, position4, 50)

  fmt.Printf("position3: %v\nposition4: %v\n", position3, position4)

  position = position3
  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    position = position.Add(vector2)
    fmt.Printf("next position: %v\n", position)
  }
}

type Position struct {
  X float64
  Y float64
}

type Vector struct {
  Radians  float64
  Distance float64
}

func CreatePathVector(pos1 *Position, pos2 *Position, speed int) *Vector {
  ydiff := pos2.Y - pos1.Y
  xdiff := pos2.X - pos1.X
  radians := math.Atan2(ydiff, xdiff)

  return &Vector{
    Radians:  radians,
    Distance: float64(speed),
  }
}

func (p *Position) Add(v *Vector) *Position {
  return &Position{
    X: p.X + math.Sin(v.Radians)*v.Distance,
    Y: p.Y + math.Cos(v.Radians)*v.Distance,
  }
}
```

Here is the output

```
position1: &{550 200}
position2: &{700 500}
next position: &{594.7213595499958 222.3606797749979}
next position: &{639.4427190999916 244.72135954999578}
next position: &{684.1640786499873 267.0820393249937}
next position: &{728.8854381999831 289.44271909999156}
next position: &{773.6067977499789 311.80339887498945}
position3: &{400 500}
position4: &{700 400}
next position: &{384.1886116991581 547.4341649025257}
next position: &{368.37722339831623 594.8683298050514}
next position: &{352.56583509747435 642.3024947075771}
next position: &{336.75444679663246 689.7366596101028}
next position: &{320.9430584957906 737.1708245126285}
```

As you can see, in both examples, the steps of adding the vector repeatedly does not steer towards the destination

Comment: Y increasing to the bottom should not be a problem! If y increases to the bottom and you want the angle between horizontal line and the straight line between player and click, the angle would be `math.Atan2(ydiff * -1, xdiff)`

Comment: @Atomic_alarm: It's not very helpful to ask a user to provide an MCVE. You need to explain what that is. Even better, provide a link to Stack Overflow's explanation: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One option is to forgo angles entirely and represent your vector in cartesian form. So you'd have a vector with {xdiff, ydiff} instead of {Radians, Distance}. After all, taking the arctangent and then taking sin/cos is just a useless conversion from cartesian to polar and immediately back to cartesian. Besides that, what exactly is the problem with the code you have? What about it doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for responses so far. I have posted MCVE.

Comment: @alaphao I have modified my program to use `math.Atan2(ydiff * -1, xdiff)` and that does not solve the issue. Can post output if desired.
@DavidEtler I may switch to {xdiff, ydiff} vector type instead. I like that suggestion.

Comment: @ZachTaylor I think you will have to check some conditions (something like `if playerX >= cursorX  { angle = atan(dy/dx) + pi` ) to work as yo expect, but it is probably better to work with vectors like @DavidEtler said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your code would look like if you chose to go with Cartesian coordinates like I suggested in the comments:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math"
)

func main() {
  position1 := &Position{550, 200}
  position2 := &Position{700, 500}
  vector1 := CreatePathVector(position1, position2, 70)

  fmt.Printf("position1: %v\nposition2: %v\n", position1, position2)

  position := position1
  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    position = position.Add(vector1)
    fmt.Printf("next position: %v\n", position)
  }

  position3 := &Position{400, 500}
  position4 := &Position{700, 400}
  vector2 := CreatePathVector(position3, position4, 50)

  fmt.Printf("position3: %v\nposition4: %v\n", position3, position4)

  position = position3
  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    position = position.Add(vector2)
    fmt.Printf("next position: %v\n", position)
  }
}

type Position struct {
  X float64
  Y float64
}

type Vector struct {
  dX  float64
  dY float64
}

func CreatePathVector(pos1 *Position, pos2 *Position, speed int) *Vector {
  ydiff := pos2.Y - pos1.Y
  xdiff := pos2.X - pos1.X
  mag := math.Sqrt(xdiff*xdiff+ydiff*ydiff)


  return &Vector{
    dX:  xdiff/mag*float64(speed),
    dY:  ydiff/mag*float64(speed),
  }
}

func (p *Position) Add(v *Vector) *Position {
  return &Position{
    X: p.X + v.dX,
    Y: p.Y + v.dY,
  }
}
```

If you want to stick with angles, just switch the `Cos` and `Sin` in the `Add`. This is because the orientation of the screen does not matter: if you take `t = arctan(y/x)` you get `y` back from `sin(t)` and `x` back from `cos(t)` regardless of what `x` and `y` represent. So add should be this:

```
func (p *Position) Add(v *Vector) *Position {
  return &Position{
    X: p.X + math.Cos(v.Radians)*v.Distance,
    Y: p.Y + math.Sin(v.Radians)*v.Distance,
  }
}
```

I've made small games before myself, and I too have tried to use angles for movement. My suggestion is don't even try. If you want to add more realistic physics to your game, vectors and linear algebra will be your best friend. Angles and trig gets too messy in my opinion.

Comment: I have finished implementing this change and it works as I expected. Thank you in particular for the snippet to create a vector of the appropriate size including move speed